# How can I get the next char even if it is whitespace?

Tags: c++, whitespace, getline, getchar

Is there a function like `getline` or `getchar` that will get the next character even if that `char` is whitespace? So if I had `a bc`, I would have to call that function four times to get the `'a'`, `' '`, `'b'`, and `'c'`.

Comment: Maybe http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws

Comment: getline gets a line with 1 call, not 4. getchar is something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

The Unformatted Input Functions do not skip whitespace - see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UnformattedInputFunction).  Sounds like you want [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).  From the full list linked above:

> The following standard library functions are UnformattedInputFunctions.

```
std::getline, except that it does not modify gcount.
basic_istream::operator>>(basic_streambuf*)
basic_istream::get
basic_istream::getline
basic_istream::ignore
basic_istream::peek
basic_istream::read
basic_istream::readsome
basic_istream::putback, except that it first clears eofbit
basic_istream::unget, except that it first clears eofbit
basic_istream::sync, except that it does not modify gcount
basic_istream::tellg, except that it does not modify gcount
basic_istream::seekg, except that it first clears eofbit and does not modify gcount
std::ws, except that it does not modify gcount
```

An alternative is to disable skipping of whitespace inside Formatted Input Functions:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
char c;
std::cin >> std::noskipws >> c;
```

Comment: ×1 for the list. Nice. Why didn't I think of that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I can't claim much credit... saw the link atop the `::get` page rather than thinking to search for it directly.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try ifstream as there is a manipulator to disable the whitespace skipping behavior:

```
stream >> std::noskipws;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading of single chars with the standard library's named character input functions, doesn't skip whitespace. I.e. the question has an incorrect assumption.

At the C++ level you can use [`istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get); there are various overloads.

At the C level, [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) and [`getwchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getwchar), plus [family](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgetc).

It's a good idea to train on finding things in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[getline(cin,variable)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Getline takes an entire line so for 'a bc', you would have to parse that string by yourself.